# How to do this trick in 'CallServer' method in implementing client callbacks programmatically without postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, callback

From this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210.aspx) we can call back server from JavaScript without post back, but I want to make CallServer method to return the result and I try it as below:

```
    string callBackReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "function(result) {alert(result);response = result;}", "context", "function(result) {response = 'Err';}", true);
    string callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context) { var response; " + callBackReference + "; return response;}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callbackScript, true);
```

and in JavaScript I do the below:

```
response = CallServer("username", "");
 alert("response:" + response);
```

Always response equal undefined although I make it asynchronous. How can I solve this problem?

### Edit

My main problem that lead me to try the above solution that my need to call 'CallServer' method in `OnClientClick` of Asp button and return true or false as below:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="return CallServer('arg','');" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET Page Methods for such problems.
Here is an [example](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx).

Also, [you can use jQuery to call an ASP.NET Page Methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Sure, you need to enable "`EnablePageMethods`" of `ScriptManager` to enable PageMethods.

Comment: i already use jquery to do that but it have some security issues speically with sharepoint

Comment: What are these security issues? How are they related to jquery/ASP.NET Ajax Methods?

Answer (score 0):

HandleResult will recieve the results from GetCallbackResult for further processing.
Add the below code to your aspx page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //the parameter arg is what is returned from GetCallbackResult
    function HandleResult(arg, context) {
        alert(arg);
    }

</script>
```